# Codename One:How does the combo box become editable?

Tags: codenameone

How does the combo box become editable in Codename One? 
It's looks like the combo box just can select-only but not enter the input and auto-select.

Comment: Going to need an example.. some code, a snippet, something. Maybe [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One doesn't provide an editable combo box. That widget type makes relatively little sense on a touch device since the virtual keyboard will pop open making combo box selection difficult. Furthermore, iOS doesn't really have a builtin native combo box only within webkit.

Codename One does have an AutoCompleteTextField which will allow you to create a somewhat similar experience to an editable combo box however it expects you to type something to begin picking the element you want.